# Creating a UICollectionView programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I'm looking for a guide or tutorial that will show me how to set up a simple UICollectionView using only code.

I'm wading through [the documentation on Apples site](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH1-SW1), and I'm using [the reference manual](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview) as well.

But I would really benefit from a simple guide that can show me how to set up a UICollectionView without having to use Storyboards or XIB/NIB files - but unfortunately when I search about, all I can find is tutorials that feature the Storyboard.

Comment: At the documentation there's a single initializer which you should use instead of any superclass initializer, where do you have problems exactly ?

Comment: Really? Ive got as far as the section "Configuring Cells and Supplimentary Views" - have I been a dumb ass and missed this line? Or have I yet to reach it?

Comment: The first task is `Initializing a Collection View`, are you using  initializer from there ?

Comment: Yes, but this in itself is not enough. I will also need to set up a datasource as well or the App crashes.

Comment: @Jimmery Now how to add image in the cell in this collectionview?

Answer (score 370, accepted):

Header file:--

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
{
    UICollectionView *_collectionView;
}
```

Implementation File:--

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

     UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    _collectionView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [_collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [_collectionView setDelegate:self];

    [_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    [_collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    [self.view addSubview:_collectionView];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 15;
}

// The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(50, 50);
}
```

Output---

[image]

Comment: You should add the collection view as property in IOS7 `@property (strong, nonatomic) UICollectionView *collectionView;`

Comment: The setup should happen in -(void)loadView, not in viewDidLoad. As for why it works, the controller first loads default views in its super. Its better to overload loadview and assign your custom views directly.

Comment: Also, if you're programmatically adding any subviews to the `UICollectionViewCell`, you really don't want to be registering `UICollectionViewCell`, but rather you want to subclass it, do your configuration of the cell in the `initWithFrame` method, and then register this subclass with the cell identifier, not `UICollectionViewCell`.

Comment: Has anyone else had an error with the above code?
It's giving me EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on the line `_collectionView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];`

Comment: 'self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];' this was missing.

Comment: it should be placed in -loadView, not in -viewDidLoad

Comment: You should never add any code before the call of the super class method in this case [super viewDidLoad]; that's a bad practice read apple documentation

Comment: why are we adding this line in? self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

Comment: hi @Rambatino just set frame to main screen bounds , no need to alloc until it is not attached with outlet.

Comment: hi @artud2000, at your suggestion I am editing my answer to get super call first executed. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @Warewolf  could you please tell me, How to change the direction of collection view to horizontal??

Answer (score 57):

**For swift4 user:--**

```
class TwoViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell")
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
       var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)

       cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
       return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
    }
}
```

Comment: Now how to add image in this programmatically collectionView ?

Comment: @ArgaPK adding subview to cell in cellForItem method

Answer (score 19):

**For Swift 2.0**

Instead of implementing the methods that are required to draw the `CollectionViewCells`:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        return CGSizeMake(50, 50);
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
    {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5); //top,left,bottom,right
    }
```

Use `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

```
func createCollectionView() {
    let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

    // Now setup the flowLayout required for drawing the cells
    let space = 5.0 as CGFloat

    // Set view cell size
    flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(50, 50)

    // Set left and right margins
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = space

    // Set top and bottom margins
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = space

    // Finally create the CollectionView
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 400), collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)

    // Then setup delegates, background color etc.
    collectionView?.dataSource = self
    collectionView?.delegate = self
    collectionView?.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellID")
    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.view.addSubview(collectionView!)
}
```

Then implement the `UICollectionViewDataSource` methods as required:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20;
    }
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var cell:UICollectionViewCell=collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("collectionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell;
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor();
    return cell;
}
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Swift 3

```
class TwoViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell")
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 20
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        return CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
    {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
    }

}
```

Comment: @ArgaPK sure, just add flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal after you instantiate the flowLayout :)

Answer (score 8):

You can handle custom cell in uicollection view see below code.[image]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  UINib *nib2 = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"YourCustomCell" bundle:nil];
    [CollectionVW registerNib:nib2 forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"YourCustomCell"];


    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(200, 230)];
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
    [CollectionVW setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];

    [CollectionVW reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - COLLECTIONVIEW
#pragma mark Collection View CODE

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return Array.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"YourCustomCell";
    YourCustomCell *cell = (YourCustomCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.MainIMG.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


    return cell;
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
}

#pragma mark Collection view layout things
// Layout: Set cell size
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGSize mElementSize;
    mElementSize=CGSizeMake(kScreenWidth/3.4, 150);
    return mElementSize;
}


- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5.0;
}

// Layout: Set Edges
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (isIphone5 || isiPhone4)
    {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(15,15,5,15);  // top, left, bottom, right
    }
    else if (isIphone6)
    {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(15,15,5,15);  // top, left, bottom, right
    }
    else if (isIphone6P)
    {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(15,15,5,15);  // top, left, bottom, right
    }

    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(15,15,5,15);  // top, left, bottom, right
}
```

Answer (score 6):

1. Building off @Warewolf's answer, the next step is to create your own custom cell.

   Go to `File -> New -> File -> User Interface -> Empty -> Call` this nib `"customNib"`.
2. In your `customNib` drag a `UICollectionView` Cell in. Give it reuse cell identifier `@"Cell"`.
3. `File -> New -> File -> Cocoa Touch Class -> Class` named `"CustomCollectionViewCell"` subclass if `UICollectionViewCell`.
4. Go back to the custom nib, click cell and make this custom class `"CustomCollectionViewCell"`.
5. Go to your `viewDidLoad` `viewcontroller` and instead of

   `[_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];`

   have

   `UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"customNib" bundle:nil];
   [_collectionView registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];`
6. Also, change (to your new cell identifier)

   `UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];`

Answer (score 1):

Apple Docs:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
      collectionViewLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)layoutParameters
```

> Use this method when initializing a collection view object
>   programmatically. If you specify nil for the layout parameter, you
>   must assign a layout object to the collectionViewLayout property
>   before displaying the collection view onscreen. If you do not, the
>   collection view will be unable to present any items onscreen.
>
> This method is the designated initializer.

This method is used to initialize the `UICollectionView`.
here you provide frame and a `UICollectionViewLayout` object.

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
```

At the end, add `UICollectionView` as a `subview` to your view.

Now collection view is added pro grammatically. You can go on learning.
Happy learning!! Hope it helps you.

Comment: But I've read in the apple doc that `The layout object to use for organizing items. The collection view stores a strong reference to the specified object. Must not be nil.`

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

**XCode 11.5**

```
import UIKit

// 1. When creating this view, instanciate this class with the param "collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout".

class BespokeCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    var cellId = "AwesomeCell"
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // 2. Register a reusable cell:
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }
    
    // 3. Return number of items:
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    
    // 4. Define the reusable cell:
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
        // You can cast type above as such: ...for: indexPath) as! BespokeCell
        return cell
    }
    
    // 5. Define the size of the cell. This depends on protocol 'UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout' to work:
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width = view.frame.width // In this example the width is the same as the whole view.
        let height = CGFloat(200)
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }
}
```

To use your bespoke class, don't forget the `collectionViewLayout` param:

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
let myViewController = WorkoutViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
```

If you're not using the storyboard, you need to attach this view to the window. That's a different problem. Systems up to iOS 12 will handle the window logic on the AppDelegate file. On iOS 13+, this logic is handled on the SceneDelegate file.

```
window?.rootViewController = someController
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark - UICollectionView Datasource and Delegates

    -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
    {
        return 1;
    }

    -(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return Arr_AllCulturalButtler.count;
    }

    -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *coll=@"FromCulturalbutlerCollectionViewCell";
        FromCulturalbutlerCollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:coll forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.lbl_categoryname.text=[[Arr_AllCulturalButtler objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] Category_name];
        cell.lbl_date.text=[[Arr_AllCulturalButtler objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] event_Start_date];
        cell.lbl_location.text=[[Arr_AllCulturalButtler objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] Location_name];
        [cell.Img_Event setImageWithURL:[APPDELEGATE getURLForMediumSizeImage:[(EventObj *)[Arr_AllCulturalButtler objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] Event_image_name]] placeholderImage:nil usingActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        cell.button_Bookmark.selected=[[Arr_AllCulturalButtler objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] Event_is_bookmarked];
        [cell.button_Bookmark addTarget:self action:@selector(btn_bookmarkClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.button_Bookmark.tag=indexPath.row;


        return cell;
    }
    - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:SEGUE_CULTURALBUTLER_KULTURELLIS_DETAIL sender:self];
    }

// stroy board navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Overview_Register"])
    {
        WDRegisterViewController *obj=(WDRegisterViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        obj.str_Title=@"Edit Profile";
        obj.isRegister=NO;
    }
}

            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Overview_Measure" sender:nil];



    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    WDPeekViewController *Peek = (WDPeekViewController *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WDPeekViewController"];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

colection view exam

```
    #import "CollectionViewController.h"
#import "BuyViewController.h"
#import "CollectionViewCell.h"

@interface CollectionViewController ()
{
    NSArray *mobiles;
    NSArray  *costumes;
    NSArray *shoes;
    NSInteger selectpath;
    NSArray *mobilerate;
    NSArray *costumerate;
    NSArray *shoerate;
}
@end

@implementation CollectionViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = self.receivename;
    mobiles = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"7.jpg",@"6.jpg",@"5.jpg", nil];
    costumes = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"shirt.jpg",@"costume2.jpg",@"costume1.jpg", nil];
    shoes = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"shoe.jpg",@"shoe1.jpg",@"shoe2.jpg", nil];
    mobilerate = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"10000",@"11000",@"13000",nil];
    costumerate = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"699",@"999",@"899", nil];
    shoerate = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"599",@"499",@"300", nil];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 3;
}
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellId = @"cell";
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellId forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *collectionImg = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

    if ([self.receivename isEqualToString:@"Mobiles"])
    {
        collectionImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[mobiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
    else if ([self.receivename isEqualToString:@"Costumes"])
    {
        collectionImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[costumes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
    else
    {
        collectionImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[shoes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
    return cell;
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    selectpath = indexPath.row;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"buynow" sender:self];
}

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"buynow"])
    {
        BuyViewController *obj = segue.destinationViewController;
        if ([self.receivename isEqualToString:@"Mobiles"])
        {
            obj.reciveimg = [mobiles objectAtIndex:selectpath];
            obj.labelrecive = [mobilerate objectAtIndex:selectpath];

        }
        else if ([self.receivename isEqualToString:@"Costumes"])
        {
            obj.reciveimg = [costumes objectAtIndex:selectpath];
            obj.labelrecive = [costumerate objectAtIndex:selectpath];
        }
        else
        {
            obj.reciveimg = [shoes objectAtIndex:selectpath];
            obj.labelrecive = [shoerate objectAtIndex:selectpath];
        }
        //     Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
        //     Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
}

@end
```

.h file

```
@interface CollectionViewController :
UIViewController<UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *receiveimg;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *receivecostume;
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSString *receivename;

@end
```

Comment: How does this differ from the 6 others answers already here? When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.

Answer (score 0):

**For whose want create a Custom Cell** :

**CustomCell.h**

```c
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface HeaderCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIImageView *image;
@end
```

**CustomCell.m**

```c
#import "HeaderCollectionViewCell.h"

@implementation HeaderCollectionViewCell
#define IMAGEVIEW_BORDER_LENGTH 5

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)setup{
    _image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRectInset(self.bounds, IMAGEVIEW_BORDER_LENGTH, IMAGEVIEW_BORDER_LENGTH))];
    [self addSubview:_image];

}
@end
```

**UIViewController.h**

```c
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
@property (strong,nonatomic) UICollectionView *collectionView;

@end
```

**UIViewController.m**

```c
#import "HomeViewController.h"
#import "HomeView.h"
#import "HeaderCollectionViewCell.h"

@interface HomeViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) NSString *cellID;

@end

@implementation HomeViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor;

    _cellID = @"id";

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    _collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];


    [_collectionView registerClass:[HeaderCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:_cellID];



    [_collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [_collectionView setDelegate:self];

    _collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;


    [self.view addSubview:_collectionView];



}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 4;
}

- (__kindof UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    HeaderCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:_cellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"premium-icon"];

    return cell;
}

-(UITabBarItem*) tabBarItem{
    return [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Início" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home-icon"] tag:0];
}


@end
```

Answer (score -2):

```
swift 4 code


//
//  ViewController.swift
//  coolectionView
//




import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var items = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        if indexPath.row % 3 != 0
        {
        return CGSize(width:collectionView.frame.width/2 - 7.5 , height: 100)
        }
        else
        {
            return CGSize(width:collectionView.frame.width - 10 , height: 100 )
        }
    }


    // make a cell for each cell index path
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        // get a reference to our storyboard cell
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell1234", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CollectionViewCell1234

        // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell
        cell.lbl1.text = self.items[indexPath.item]
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan // make cell more visible in our example project
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8

        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // handle tap events
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
    }



}
```

Comment: How are you binding this view controller as a delegate to the collection view layout?