# ios UICollectionView separation on top / bottom between cells

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a collection view, is working fine, and I have adjusted the separation for the X padding,

and it works fine,
but for the Y padding between cells, doesn't seem to adjust to NO separation

This is my code for the layout

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layoutItem=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    layoutItem.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

[image]
So how can I set the separation on top / bottom to 0px? Between cells?,

thanks!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

you will see only top y padding at first time.
And For showing bottom y padding you need more data that CollectionView frame height. When you scroll up collection view you will see bottom y padding.

I used collectionView like this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17856406/1305001

When I set

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(60, 10, 50, 10);
}
```

The output will come as First time..

[image]

When you scrolled up collectionView you will see bottom padding..

[image]

Use this for verticle line spacing between cells

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}
```

Will look like

[image]

Comment: hi thanks, my mistake I didn’t explain properly, is the separation between cells on top, bottom, meaning, no space on y between cells, I edited my question and up-voted you thanks

Comment: check edited answer,pass 0 instead of 5 will let you have no vertical space between cells.

Answer (score 5):

You can also do it a much simpler way using the collection view flow layout.

Set up the flow layout (remember to add the delegate in your header):

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout * stickerFlowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

stickerFlowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
**stickerFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 10;**
stickerFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5;
stickerFlowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 25, 20, 25);

// Set up the collection view 
collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero collectionViewLayout:stickerFlowLayout];
collectionView.delegate = self;
collectionView.dataSource = self;

etc
```

As you can see we can easily set the line spacing using:

```
**stickerFlowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 10;**
```

We can also alter the other attributes

```
stickerFlowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5;
```

With the interitem spacing affecting the spaces between items (similar but different to the line spacing)

Using the flow layout you can save on a huge amount of code and set your collection view up programatically all in one place (just setting the inset and line spacing has immediately saved me two extra unneeded functions)