# Load image to UICollectionView Asynchronously?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, uicollectionview

How can i load images to a `UICollectionview` asynchronously?
Inside following method?

```
- (PSTCollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(PSTCollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 bookImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docPath, [[preview objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] lastPathComponent]]];
 [[cell grid_image] setImage:bookImage];

}
```

In **viewdidload()** i am using following asynch call to load images to "preview "`NSMutablearray`

```
 dispatch_queue_t imageLoadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.GMM.assamkar", NULL);

dispatch_async(imageLoadQueue, ^{
    //Wait for 5 seconds...
    usleep(1000000);
    docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];


    for(int k=0; k <[allImage count] ;k++){


        imgURL = [allImage objectAtIndex:k];
        [imagePreview addObject:imgURL];
        imgData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgURL]];


        [imgData writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docPath, [allImage lastPathComponent]] atomically:YES];

    }

    [[self collectionView] reloadData];


});
```

Please help me..Now its taking too much time for loading...

Comment: What is taking too long specifically? And what size are the images?

Comment: you should make this [[self collectionView] reloadData]; in main thread. It isn't an answer. It's comment only.

Comment: use EGOImageView  :
https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading

Answer (score 9):

Trying to answer your main question "How can i load images to a `UICollectionview` asynchronously?"

I would suggest solution offered by "*Natasha Murashev*" [here](http://natashatherobot.com/ios-how-to-download-images-asynchronously-make-uitableview-scroll-fast/), which worked nicely for me and it's simple.

If here `imgURL = [allImage objectAtIndex:k];` in `allImage` property you keep array of URLs, then update your `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method like this:

```
- (PSTCollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(PSTCollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[allImage objectAtIndex:indexPath]];

    [self downloadImageWithURL:url completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSData *data) {
        if (succeeded) {
            cell.grid_image.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        }
    }];
}
```

And add method `downloadImageWithURL:completionBlock:` to your class, which will load images asynchronously and update cells in CollectionView automatically when images are successfully downloaded.

```
- (void)downloadImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url completionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL succeeded, NSData *data))completionBlock
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            completionBlock(YES, data);
        } else {
            completionBlock(NO, nil);
        }
    }];
}
```

I see you try to preload images before view appears so maybe my solution isn't what you what, but from your question it's hard to say. Any how, you can achieve what you want with this as well.

**Swift 2.2**
Solution in Swift.

```
public typealias ImageFetchCompletionClosure = (image: UIImage?, error: NSError?, imageURL: NSURL?) -> Void

extension String {
   func fetchImage(completionHandler: (image: UIImage?, error: NSError?, imageURL: NSURL?) -> Void) {
        if let imageURL = NSURL(string: self) {
            NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(imageURL) { data, response, error in
                guard
                    let httpURLResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                    let mimeType = response?.MIMEType where mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
                    let data = data where error == nil,
                    let image = UIImage(data: data)
                    else {
                        if error != nil {
                            completionHandler(image: nil, error: error, imageURL: imageURL)
                        }
                        return
                }
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
                    completionHandler(image: image, error: nil, imageURL: imageURL)
                }
            }.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

Usage sample:

```
    "url_string".fetchImage { (image, error, imageURL) in
        // handle different results, either image was downloaded or error received
    }
```

Comment: Isn't it like cells can be reused and you efficiently overwrite the cell with some other image data? Also cell is undefined in your sample ;)

Comment: It's mainly meant to answer how to load images asynchronously, not how to work efficiently with cells :) Though, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

This code creates serial queue:

```
dispatch_queue_t imageLoadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.GMM.assamkar", NULL);
```

therefore each task IN QUEUE is performed in the same thread successive. Therefore your single work thread is sustained by sleep for each task of loading that slow down all process of loading.

Use asynchronous CONCURRENT queue by using something like that:

```
dispatch_queue_t imageLoadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.GMM.assamkar", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
```

Comment: So and use reloadData on the main thread. Like that                          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ //reloadData });

Comment: i think i should use a new lazy loading method to disaplay for my PSTCollectionView

Answer (score -1):

Use Lazy Load File for your requirement.

[LazyLoad.h](https://gist.github.com/ipreencekmr/6146285)
[LazyLoad.m](https://gist.github.com/ipreencekmr/6146286)

Use them like this

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell addSubview:[self addViewWithURL:@"http://openwalls.com/image/399/explosion_of_colors_1920x1200.jpg" NFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)]];

    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    return cell;
}

-(UIView*)addViewWithURL:(NSString*)urlStr NFrame:(CGRect)rect
{
    LazyLoad *lazyLoading;

    lazyLoading = [[LazyLoad alloc] init];
    [lazyLoading setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [lazyLoading setFrame:rect];

    [lazyLoading loadImageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
    return lazyLoading;
}
```

[Download Demo Here](http://ge.tt/83goHmn/v/0)

Comment: How can i display images in UICollectionview cell.imageview.image   ,thats my question

Comment: cell.imageview.image property not exists in CollectionView only in tableView.MyCode will load image asynchronously and add as subview in collectionView cell.

Comment: add myCode with http://stackoverflow.com/a/17856406/1305001 or u need to use custom cell instead

Comment: your code is not working AND THE LINK FOR /H AND .M FILES ARE EMPTY

Comment: Heloo ,i need to disaply that in cell.image  my custome cell imageview  but u r using  uiview .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34763/discussion-between-navi-and-hercules)

Comment: The LazyLoad class solved my initial problem but opened a new one. The images won't load before the view finishes to scroll. Is there a way to have them load as soon as they enter the screen while scrolling?