# Subclassing NSURLConnection gives error: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, nsurlconnection, subclass

i'm trying to make a subclass of `NSURLConnection` where i have an additional property (in this case "connectionName") to help me distinguish between 2 different connections.

i created the subclass, named it `CustomURLConnection` and gave it the property "connectionName".

then in my file ImagesViewController.m (which is an `UICollectionView`) i import the header `CustomURLConnection` and try to give the connections a name and retrieve it afterwards, but it doesn't work, as soon as i enter this collection view the app crashes and gives me the following error:

**-[NSURLConnection setConnectionName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1090a40f0**

Here is some code: (if you want, here's a [CLEARER IMAGE](http://oi61.tinypic.com/nntetv.jpg))

**CustomURLConnection.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CustomURLConnection : NSURLConnection

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *connectionName;

@end
```

**ImagesViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ImagesViewController : UICollectionViewController<NSURLConnectionDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *imageView;

@end
```

**ImagesViewController.m**

```
...
#import "CustomURLConnection.h"

@interface ImagesViewController (){
    NSArray *contentStrings;
    NSMutableData *contentData; // Holds data from the initial load
    NSMutableData *contentImageData; // Holds data when the user scrolls up/down in the collection view
}
@end

...

-(void)loadInitialData{ // Loads data from page
    NSString *hostStr = @"http://www.website.com/example";
    NSURL *dataURL = [NSURL URLWithString:hostStr];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:dataURL];
    CustomURLConnection *connectionData = (CustomURLConnection *)[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self]; // Make connection
    connectionData.connectionName = @"InitialData"; // Give it a name
}

...

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    // Do some stuff

    NSString *hostStr = @"http://www.website.com/example2";

    _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
    [imageCell addSubview:_imageView]; // Adds an image view to each collection cell

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:hostStr]];
    CustomURLConnection *connectionImg = (CustomURLConnection *)[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self]; // Make connection
    connectionImg.connectionName = @"ImageData"; // Give it a different name than before

    // Do some stuff
    return imageCell;
}

...

// Here are the main methods for the connections
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    if([((CustomURLConnection *)connection).connectionName isEqualToString:@"InitialData"]){
        contentData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }
    else{
        contentImageData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    if([((CustomURLConnection *)connection).connectionName isEqualToString:@"InitialData"]){
        [contentData appendData:data];
    }
    else{
        [contentImageData appendData:data];
    }
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    if([((CustomURLConnection *)connection).connectionName isEqualToString:@"InitialData"]){
        // Do some stuff
    }
    else{
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:contentImageData];
        _imageView.image = image;
    }
}
```

am i missing something? i came across this error many times before but the causes are never the same and this time i can't seem to find a solution on my own.

hopefully you can see what i'm doing wrong and help me :)
thanks.

EDIT: turns out there is a better way to achieve my goal, [have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18030978/load-image-to-uicollectionview-asynchronously)
Thank again to everyone for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your delegate methods change NSURLConnection by CustomURLConnection, for instance :

```
- (void)connection:(CustomURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
```

and when you create it just do :

```
CustomURLConnection *connectionImg = [[CustomURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
connectionImg.connectionName = @"ImageData"; // Give it a different name than before
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the super fast reply!
i tried to do that already and it gave me the same results, and isn't it the same as i do now (casting the custom class during the comparison?)  

    if([((CustomURLConnection *)connection).connectionName isEqualToString:@"InitialData"])

Comment: Actually yes if you consider that you'll always get a CustomURLConnection, but this could lead to the same error if you are sending just a NSURLConnection. I just edited my answer, the cause of your problem is also in your nsurlconnection creation.

Comment: thanks for the help, unfortunately when i edit the code with your example (create an object of class CustomURLConnection) it gives me a waning: Incompatible pointer types initializing 'CustomURLConnection *' with an expression of type 'NSURLConnection *'. I tried to run the app but it still crashes, i also tried to cast the CustomURLClass in front of the expression to get rid of the warning, but the app still doesn't work and the error is the same as before. maybe i should create a custom expression for my subclass?

Comment: I'm not sure why it does not work, however creating it with [[CustomURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self]; works for me. (updated my answer)

Comment: Tried with alloc and it doesn't crash anymore, thanks! now i only see the last image on the collection view...not sure why, but i'll hopefully find out by myself. Thanks again for the help, very appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

```
CustomURLConnection *connectionImg = (CustomURLConnection *)[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self]; // Make connection
```

creates an `NSURLConnection` object. Casting to `CustomURLConnection` does not change
the class of this object. Replace that line with

```
CustomURLConnection *connectionImg = [CustomURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self]; // Make connection
```

to create an instance of your subclass.

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
CustomURLConnection *connectionData = (CustomURLConnection *)[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

you are creating an instance of `NSURLConnection`, not `CustomURLConnection`. So, when you cast the result to `CustomURLConnection *` you are lying to the compiler.

Later, at runtime, when you try to use a feature of `CustomURLConnection` you get an exception because your `connection` is the wrong class type and doesn't implement the method.

You need to instantiate `CustomURLConnection`, not `NSURLConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the other good answers here, your `CustomURLConnection` class should override `+connectionWithRequest:delegate:` to return an instance of `CustomURLConnection`, like this:

```
+(CustomURLConnection*)connectionWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request delegate:(id)delegate
{
    return [[CustomURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:delegate];
}
```

That lets you use the same style you had:

```
CustomURLConnection *connectionData = [CustomURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self]; // Make connection
```

More importantly, a user of your code (most likely the future you) might assume that sending `+connectionWithRequest:delegate:` to `CustomURLConnection` would return an instance of `CustomURLConnection`. Without the override, they'll get an instance of `NSURLConnection` instead, and that's a difficult bug to spot.