# Image picker on slider

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I want to create image slider [Same like an bellow image].I got some example but those are not fulfilling my requirement. Please help me to solve this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) is the best choice for your task. See example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856055/creating-a-uicollectionview-programmatically).

Comment: I already saw these examples but i didn't worked on collection view. So, i am not getting how to make it vertically.

Comment: why do you want to make it vertically. I see horizontal layout on attached screenshot.

Comment: So sorry for this mistake..Thank you. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: If you need vertical layout use: `[layout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got the solution here- https://github.com/macelangelo/HorizontalCollectionViews