# iOS CollectionView crash

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm trying to add `UICollectionView` to my app with auto layout, but it keeps crashing. This is my code:

```
_collection = [[UICollectionView alloc] init];
[_collection registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellId];
_collection.collectionViewLayout = [DXSelectionViewLayout new];
_collection.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
_collection.dataSource = self;
_collection.hidden = YES;
```

Error:

```
2014-05-14 16:16:09.978 Sportlinked[4712:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'
```

Comment: as the crash indicates i guess the problem might be in line _collection.collectionViewLayout = [DXSelectionViewLayout new];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `UICollectionView`s you need to use

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame collectionViewLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)layout
```

as initializer - instead of the plain

```
- (id)init
```

method.

(The collection view *must* be initialized with a layout.)

So practically replace your first line of code with something like this in order to create a collection view properly:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200); // sample frame
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout= [UICollectionViewFlowLayout new]; // standard flow layout
_collection = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:frame collectionViewLayout:layout];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find your answer there :

[Creating a UICollectionView programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856055/creating-a-uicollectionview-programmatically)

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
_collectionView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];
```

Comment: So A collection can't use auto layout?

Comment: @MouNtant You can still use auto-layout to position your collection view.  You can just pass an approximately-sized CGRect in as the frame if you're doing so.