# Creating a UICollectionView within a subview

Tags: ios, ios7, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a view controller (that sits in a tab bar controller), but need to add a collection view to that controller.  I see lots of tutorials on google but they all seem to point to creating a `UICollectionViewController` and starting in `viewDidLoad`.  But how do I do it in a subview?

I have my view controller.m file like so:

```
- (void) createView // called from viewDidLoad
{

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 64.0, screenWidth, screenHeight)];

    [scrollView.layer addGradient];

    ACollectionView *theview = [[ACollectionView alloc] init];

    [self.view addSubview:theview];
}
```

Next I started a `UICollectionView` subclass called `ACollectionView.h`

```
@interface ACollectionView : UICollectionView

@end
```

And the .m file is this:

```
#import "ACollectionView.h"

@implementation BestCollectionView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
```

Where do I start the collection view, in the `initWithFrame`?

I am trying to follow this:
[Creating a UICollectionView programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856055/creating-a-uicollectionview-programmatically)

Is my paradigm correct?

Comment: What the use of subclassing here.

Comment: no reason, what's the better way?

Comment: I think your requirement is like add UICollectionView programatically(other than in ViewDidload).r8?.Add it into subview means ,you have a subview on that VC and u want to add UICollectionView to that subview.r8?

Comment: yes I want to add a UICollectionView to my page programmatically

Comment: You can do that in ViewDidload itself.Thats the better practice.Becoz that will call only once.Y u trying to avoid ViewDidload?

Comment: I'm not trying to avoid it, just abstracting and learning best practices and reading docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UICollectionView *collectionView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
     UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.yourSubview.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [self.collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [self.collectionView setDelegate:self];

    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];

    [self.yourSubview addSubview:self.collectionView];

}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 50;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(100, 100);
}
```

Comment: so i can drop this directly in my base view controller that is tab 1 of my tab bar controller?

Comment: Coll how do I change the background color to a gradient? I have a CALayer gradient I want to add and have the red dots appear above it?

Comment: Yea.use this CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = self.collectionView.bounds;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], nil];
[self.collectionView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];