# How do you add a UICollectionViewController to a UIScrollview within a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, ios7, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to use this as a starting point to learn about collection view: [Creating a UICollectionView programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856055/creating-a-uicollectionview-programmatically)

I have a viewDidLoad which has a UIScrollView created like so:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 64.0,
```

screenWidth, screenHeight)];

How do I add in the UICollectionViewController as the following below doesn't work:

```
ACollectionViewControllerr *vc = [[ACollectionViewController alloc] init];

[self.view addSubview:vc];
```

Do you need a UIScrollView to scroll down or does uicollectionview have that functionality already?

Answer (score 1):

`UICollectionView` inherits from `UIScrollView`, so you don't need to add an `UIScrollView`. Just add the `UICollectionView` to the `UIViewController` directly.

If you use `UICollectionViewController` then you don't require `UIViewController`.

See the documentation of [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add a ViewController to a view, which will not work. Try the following instead:

```
ACollectionViewControllerr *vc = [[ACollectionViewController alloc] init];

[self.view addSubView:vc.view];
[vc didMoveToParentViewController];
```

Comment: Ohk, I missed out the last sentance in the question. Yogesh's answer is more appropriate.