# how to display images horizontal UIscrollView Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I did Get images for Url.and then display on SCrollView.My code like this

```
 NSMutableArray *al=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];
    for (NSDictionary *diction in al)
    {


       NSString *geting =[diction valueForKey:@"dealimage"];
        NSLog(@"dealimage is %@",geting);

        NSData *getdata=[[NSData alloc]initWithData:[NSData dataFromBase64String:geting]];
        NSLog(@"good day %@",getdata);
        dataimages=[UIImage imageWithData:getdata];
        NSLog(@"dataimages %@",dataimages);

        [imagesarray addObject:dataimages];


     }

scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]init];

    scrollView.delegate = self;
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    int scrollWidth = 100;
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth,100);
    scrollView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100);
    scrollView.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];

    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    int xOffset = 0;
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagesName objectAtIndex:0]];

    for(int index=0; index < [imagesName count]; index++)
    {

        UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        img.bounds = CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50);
        img.frame = CGRectMake(5+xOffset, 0, 160, 110);
        NSLog(@"image: %@",[imagesName objectAtIndex:index]);
        img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagesName objectAtIndex:index]];
        [images insertObject:img atIndex:index];
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth+xOffset,110);

        [scrollView addSubview:[images objectAtIndex:index]];

        xOffset += 170;
    }
```

my Problem is ScrollView is Display but Images are not add So please tell me what wrong in my code

now i need like this [image: image2]

I know how to get images for Url.now i need display images Horizontal ScrollView So Please give me any idea about  images .

Comment: Why do you comment "Please look once my question" on every answer you get?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber sorry my intention is i am changed question so jest intimated to all

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your coding is Fine, but you are assign the value of `[scrollView addSubview:[images objectAtIndex:index]];`, this is not the fine one, I modify your code, as per your result Want

```
UIScrollView  *scrollVie=[[UIScrollView alloc]init];

scrollVie.delegate = self;
scrollVie.scrollEnabled = YES;
int scrollWidth = 100;
//scrollVie.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth,100);
scrollVie.frame=CGRectMake(0, 51, self.view.frame.size.width, 100);
scrollVie.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];




int xOffset = 0;

for(int index=0; index < [imagesarray count]; index++)
{

    UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOffset,10,160, 110)];
    img.image = (UIImage*) [imagesarray objectAtIndex:index];

    [scrollVie addSubview:img];

    xOffset+=100;


}

[self.view addSubview:scrollVie];

scrollVie.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth+xOffset,110);
```

Answer (score 2):

"official" example created by Apple take a look at the [StreetScroller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/StreetScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011102) Demo.

Comment: Please look once my question

Comment: @user3781721-- this is also nice answer

Answer (score 1):

For the desired outcome that is shown in the picture, ie, the horizontal scroll,
Use ScrollView instead of tableview.

set the pane of scroll to horizontal and dynamically create imageview inside a loop and insert images inside it

hope it helps :)

Comment: @iosGure thanks for Reply Please i am now to this Field Please give me any link about you'r answer

Comment: Check out the Apple documentation for scrollview..
Here is another link u can check it out [link](http://code4app.net/ios/PHSideScrollingImagePicker/526e82f46803fa9e06000001) **bold**

Comment: @iosGuru Please look once my question

Comment: @LightYagami Please look once my question

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using table view why don't you user UICollectionView with their delegates.

you can refer this - [Creating a UICollectionView programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856055/creating-a-uicollectionview-programmatically)

It's best way to achieve your requirement.

Comment: thanks for reply i will try but i don't know about Scrollview On UICollectionViewCell please give me any link about that

Comment: Most welcome, why don't you go through this - [UIcollection view in detail](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12)

Comment: Please look once my question