# How do I make my UIView scrollable horizontally programmatically using Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I have created nine table view controllers using page view controller  and UIView. Inside UIView, there are nine buttons to points the table view controller.

My problem is, I want to make my UIView scrollable programmatically. In my project, all the buttons are in the same controller and no space to move.

Can anyone help?

My project image:

[image]

Comment: use UICollectionView for same

Comment: see this it will helps  you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24837202/how-to-display-images-horizontal-uiscrollview-programmatically/24858478#24858478

Answer (score 0):

use UICollectionView and set UICollectionView.pagingEnabled = YES.
UIScrollView is the same but you need to do something for sub views and scrollView contentSize.

Answer (score 0):

use `HMSegmentedControl` third party for same