# How to create and use UIcollectionView programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview

I have searched a lot for creating a `UICollectionView` programatically but none of them suggest the simplest way to use it, how to add a label or an image to the `UICollectionViewCell`. Most of the sites suggest that implementation of `UICollectionView` is same as `UITableView`, but the major difference comes when we try to add any image. In `UITableView` we can allocate the imageViews in `cellForRow` method where `cell == nil` and assign images where (`cell != nil`). but here in case of `UICollectionView ItemAtIndexPath` method, there is no condition (`cell == nil`) as in `UITableView`'s `CellForRow`. As a result we can't effectively allocate variables of `UImageView`s or Labels etc in `itemAtIndexPath` method. I Want to know whether there is any alternative other than subclassing the `UICollectionViewCell` and allocating variables in that custom Class? Can any one help, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this blog post and the corresponding github repository I did helps you: http://dasdev.de/2013/12/27/delegate-and-data-source-of-collection-views/

Comment: ya to some extent but we have to subclass the NSObject in the link u suggested. So To add a label, theres no otherway other than subclassing which is not needed in uitableview class. Thanks anyway.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856055/creating-a-uicollectionview-programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not alternative to create or allocate cells in itemAtIndex method. We need to register the customised class to create any views inside the custom class. something like this :

```
[UICollectionView registerClass:[CustomCollectionViewClass class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
```

[here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150111063848/https://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/paul-dakessian/ios-6-tutorial-getting-started-collection-views) is the best link which I found useful. Hope it helps others

Answer (score 1):

swift :

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
       layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
       layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 70, height: 70)

       let demoCollectionView:UICollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
       demoCollectionView.dataSource = self
       demoCollectionView.delegate = self
       demoCollectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
       demoCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
       self.view.addSubview(demoCollectionView)
   }

   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return 27
   }

   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
       cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
       return cell
   }

   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
  {
       print("User tapped on item \(indexPath.row)")
   }
```