# use of undeclared identifier collectionView

Tags: ios

i am trying to create `collectionView` but it creates error as:
use of undeclared identifier in `collectionView`.

```
- (UICollectionView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
               cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  UICollectionViewCell *cell =
      [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];

  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UICollectionViewCell alloc] init];

    [UICollectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
  }

  [self.view addSubview:__collectionView];

  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Comment: Have you registered cell with the identifier `MyIdentifier `? or do you have a prototype cell in the storyboard with that ID?

Comment: You dont have to create cell, you have to do either of the two things asi mentioned in the above comment

Comment: i didnt use storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using prototypeCell in the storyboard. You could either register Cell/Xib with the collectionView. Do this in `viewDidLoad`

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class]
forCellWithReuseIdentifier: @"MyIdentifier"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Registe your nib in view Did load method...

```
UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"NibCell" bundle:nil];
[self.collectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell"];
```

now run your app...

Comment: Error in this line                                                                                               - (UICollectionView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: NO plz add  your nib file (Cell ) in method view did load in .m file ..                       for more info ...    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856055/creating-a-uicollectionview-programmatically

Comment: yes it come bcs you don't register your cell so first register cell ... visit url may help you......http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2012/09/a-simple-uicollectionview-tutorial/