# Get value from custom cell on cell touch

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

I am a little new to iOS and I am working with a `UICollectionView`. My `UICollectionView` cells are populated with values from my array from my restful server. 
So I pull those down and assign the fields, ID, Name and text. When I tap a specific cell. I want to send the ID Of that cell (The ID which we just pulled down) and send it as a parameter to my php. So far I am populating my collectionview with the IDs,  but my problem occurs when I tap the cell, I am unsure how to get the ID.In the `didSelectCellAtIndex` method I am trying to get the cell id using

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
//dictionary[indexPath.row].;
cell.
```

However I am not sure how to refer to the property I want. Since in

```
cellForItemAtIndexPath
```

I defined  the label I want as this

```
UILabel *myid=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
```

Any help to assigning the ID in the label to a variable to send to my php will be appreciated.

Comment: Don't get the data from the cell. Get the data from the data used to populate the cell.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to create a custom cell (subclass of `UICollectionViewCell`) with properties for each subview thats needs to be configured (`IBOutlet` if you using xib/storyboard). So that they can be accessed. Like so:

```
@interface MyCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *IDLabel;

@end
```

You can access it directly:

```
MyCollectionViewCell *cell = (MyCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.IDLabel
```

---

Or like this:

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UILabel *myid=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
NSString *id = myid.text;
```

---

I think you can also access the ID from your dataSource(e.g. IDs) through the indexPath.

```
NSString *id = IDs[indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Hi The second method worked, Id actually thought of this but, I was of the assumption this would create a new label with tag 103. not reference the one already existing. However while experimenting i discovered if i wrote dictionary[indexPath.row].   ( . connotation ) it would load a list of properties and objects including the id I was trying to access but I was unsure how to assign it to a string or could it even be done from there?. (PS. your third method seemed similar to it but that doesnt work)

Comment: Why doesn't work the third method? Are you using `dictionary[indexPath.row]`? It seems like a dictionary not a array.

Comment: Like I said I used the second method and not sure why the third doesnt work, was hoping you'd shed some light

Comment: What is IDs? the the equivalent of the label i called myid? (refer to my code)

Comment: No, It should be your data source. How do you give `myid.text` a value?

Answer (score 0):

The Best way to Create UICollectionView is from the below link

> [Creating a UICollectionView programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856055/creating-a-uicollectionview-programmatically)

In this code their is a method `cellForItemAtIndexPath` in that you create subview inside it like below

if you want to use UILabel as Subview then follow this Code.

```
UILabel *lblName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];

if(lblName == nill)
{

//initalize the label.
    lblName =[[UIlabel alloc]init];   
    lblName.tag=1;
}

else

{

//assign value for that label

}
```

you can create by this way all the subview in CollectionViewCell. Just do not forget to add tag in this else it will alway create new labels for the cell.