# Unable to rearrange the cells in UICollectionView by moving them?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I have UICollectionView on which i am displaying the **custom** cells.I am trying to move the cells by making long press gesture but it does not work at all.

I have followed [this](http://nshint.io/blog/2015/07/16/uicollectionviews-now-have-easy-reordering/) tutorial but it does not working for me.Please tell how to do this?

**Long Press gesture**

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{

    NSLog(@"long press geture called");
    switch(gestureRecognizer.state)
    {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.collection_view];
          gesture_indexPath = [self.collection_view indexPathForItemAtPoint:p];
        [self.collection_view beginInteractiveMovementForItemAtIndexPath:gesture_indexPath];
            NSLog(@"state began called");

                     break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:

        //    collectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.locationInView(gesture.view!))
            [self.collection_view updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:[gestureRecognizer view]]];
            NSLog(@"state changed called");
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
            [self.collection_view updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition:p];
                  NSLog(@"state changed called");
        default:
            [self.collection_view cancelInteractiveMovement];
    }
}
```

**Method Overidden**

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView moveItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Move at index path called");
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You're missing `break;` statements inside the *switch-case* block.  Without a `break;` at the end of each *case* section, the switch-case statement isn't exited, and the next line is executed.

For completeness, here's a minimum implementation in Objective-C for a reorderable `UICollectionView`.

Implementing reordering for a `UICollectionView` **not** embedded inside a `UICollectionViewController` (probably instead inside a `UIViewController`, but maybe inside a `UICollectionViewCell` or `UITableViewCell` if you're getting fancy) requires the following three parts at a minimum:

1. Inside `viewDidLoad` (or, if you're embedding a `UICollectionView` inside a `UITableViewCell` or a `UICollectionViewCell` set up in a storyboard, this codes goes inside `awakeFromNib`), add a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to your `UICollectionView` like this:

   ```
   UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longGR = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)
   [self.yourCollectionView addGestureRecognizer:longGR];
   ```
2. Implement `handleLongPress:` to react to the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` you just added:

   ```
   - (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gr{   
       switch(gr.state){
           case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
           {
               NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.yourCollectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:[gr locationInView:self.yourCollectionView]];
               if(selectedIndexPath == nil) break;
               [self.yourCollectionView beginInteractiveMovementForItemAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath];
               break;
           }
           case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
           {
               [self.yourCollectionView updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition:[gr locationInView:gr.view]];
               break;
           }
           case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
           {
               [self.yourCollectionView endInteractiveMovement];
               break;
           }
           default:
           {
               [self.yourCollectionView cancelInteractiveMovement];
               break;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Finally, add the following:

   ```
   - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView moveItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath{

       //add your data source manipulation logic here
       //specifically, change the order of entries in the data source to match the new visual order of the cells.
       //even without anything inside this function, the cells will move visually if you build and run

   }
   ```

....and the cells will now magically move when you touch, hold, then drag!

(This all assumes that you've implemented the standard `UICollectionView` *dataSource* and *delegate* methods and the `UICollectionView` is successfully loading/displaying in your app.  If you need help with the basic set-up of a `UICollectionView`, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17856406/1114876) by Warewolf ).

Answer (score 0):

Your switch statement is falling through (one of the perils of translating a blog post written in Swift to Objective-C). Every call to the handler with a change in touch position executes every statement below the Changed: case, including cancelInteractiveMovement (On another note, that should likely be endInteractiveMovement).