# Adding subview into UICollectionView programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

Follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856055/creating-a-uicollectionview-programmatically) on SO I be able to create `UICollectionView` programmatically. But I can't find any better solution when I try to add subview into `UICollectionViewCell`. Here is how most answer on SO achieve

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
    image.image = /*some image*/
    [cell addSubview:image];
    return cell;
}
```

Maybe i'm wrong but the purpose of using `UICollectionView` wasn't because of recycle and reuse to optimize the performance? If using the code above when the user scrolling wasn't it add more and more `UIImageView` into `UICollectionViewCell` subview when `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` get trigger?

So what is the better way to do this? I can't use `UITableView` for this because I need the horizontal scrolling technique.

**NOTE:** I need to create it programmatically without using xib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It will add `imageView` everytime when your collection view will get scrolled! And it is not good approach. Now, what you can do is, Take one image view in your `collectionview cell`, I mean in interface builder(xib or storyboard whatever you have used) and in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` just `show or hide` that image view as per need or change image of it as per requirement!

**Update :**

If you have create collection view programmatically then you can set some flag in your `cellForItemAtIndexPath`! Take one flag and set it after adding `imageview`. and you can declare `imageview` and `flag` as global variable. Something like,

```
   if (!isImageAdded) {

    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
    imageView.image = /*some image*/
    [cell addSubview:image];
    isImageAdded = YES;
}
else{

    imageView.image = /*some image*/
}
```

Comment: Thx for reply. I understand how to create it with XIB but what I need is to create it programatically without using XIB or storyboard. Is it possible?

Comment: Thx that what I need