# How to set collection view programmatically in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionviewlayout

I am  a newbie trying to learn how to set collection view programatically

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()    
window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController : HomeController(collectionViewLayout:layout))
```

I am trying to get above swift code in Objective C. What I have done so far is listed below results in error. What are the changes i have to make in objc code to achieve above.

```
ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc] init];  // @interface ViewController : UICollectionViewController  
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init]; 
self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[controller collectionViewLayout:layout]] ; // ERROR How to set Collection View?
```

Comment: this is what u want,see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856055/creating-a-uicollectionview-programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I have not understand what you want to achieve...

What you need is to add a custom init method to your `ViewController`. For example:

```
// In your .h file
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController

- (instancetype)initWithCollectionViewLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout;

@end

// In your .m file
@interface HomeViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UICollectionViewLayout* collectionViewLayout;

@end

@implementation HomeViewController

- (instancetype)initWithCollectionViewLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _collectionViewLayout = collectionViewLayout;
    }
    return self;
}

// Other code here

@end
```

You can use the code like the following:

```
[[HomeViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout:yourLayout];
```

Otherwise, instead of using a constructor injection, you can do a property injection.

```
// In your .h file
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) UICollectionViewLayout* collectionViewLayout;

@end
```

And use that code like:

```
HomeViewController* vc = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
vc.collectionViewLayout = yourLayout;
```

Comment: Thanks . i edited code now errors gone . Is this the correct way? self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[controller initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout]];