# How to show Alert if CollectionView cell is not selected in Swift 3?

Tags: swift3, uialertview, collectionview

I am working on a Doctor Appointment App. I have a collection view in which cells are time slots. User can select time slot based on date of his favour.I placed a button under the collection view and after clicking that button user moves to next viewController. I want to show alert on clicking a button if user doesn't select any time slot. I tried a lot but not finding a solution. Thanks in advance....
check the screenshot of my view. Hoping someone would help me....

Comment: add some code snippet what you have tried.

Comment: sorry, I tried finding a solution for that not in terms of coding...

Comment: I am not getting an idea how to implement that...once knowing that idea I can implement that..

Comment: have you implemented collection view (https://stackoverflow.com/a/26837134/1305001)

Comment: you need to apply check in array (that you will use to display data in collectionView) using loop. If none of the element is selected then show alert otherwise proceed.

Comment: Yeah I implemented collection view. I am controlling collection view data with two buttons, left arrow button and right arrow button. Between those two buttons I placed a label and displaying date on that. when user clicking on those arrow buttons date will be changed and collection view below that label will be reloaded displaying time slots. I am displaying time slots using a dictionary which contain times and their status. I didn't understood how to apply check. can u please elaborate

Comment: Thanks for your reply....

Comment: `create an empty array -> then inside did select method add or remove elements to that array -> then when you click on that button check your array and show your alert`

Comment: In dictionary add additional key named selected of type bool. Default value will be 0 whenever user selects set its value to 1 that will indicate as selected.

Comment: thanks both of u... I ll implement

Comment: I implemented the functionality...
thanks a lot both of u for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

proceed as following:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
            if timeSlotsCollectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems == [] {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "DID NOT SELECT A TIME SLOT", message: "Please select a time slot!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
}
```

Good luck with your App